# What is the error of this Blazor EditForm?

Tags: .net, blazor

I tried to follow the instruction of creating form from youtube channel like those:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfqQ_fhmPOQ
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40njRXr6eUo
or I even tried a very simple code like this

```
    <EditForm Model="@author" OnValidSubmit="SaveAuthor">
            <p>
                <label></label>
                <InputText id="FirstName" @bind-Value="author.FirstName"/>
            </p>
     </EditForm>
```

Here is my github link for the code sample https://github.com/maxrena/BlazorServerApp.git
It still returns the error like this 
[image]
Please help me with it.

Comment: That is a very different error now.  Add the code for that sets `author`.

Comment: Btw, you don't need the `@` in front of `author` in this case, for example:  `<EditForm Model="author" OnValidSubmit="SaveAuthor">`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
if ((EditContext == null) == (Model == null))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(EditForm)} requires a {nameof(Model)} " +
        $"parameter, or an {nameof(EditContext)} parameter, but not both.");
}
```

You did not instantiate your model, and you do not have an EditContext

You've probably did this: `Author author;`

You should instantiate your object as done below:

You can do something like this:

```
   @code {
       Author author = new Author();
       public class Author
       {
          public string FirstName {get; set;} = "Charls"; 
        }
   }
```

Running sample:

```
    <EditForm Model="@author" OnValidSubmit="SaveAuthor">
    <p>
        <label></label>
        <InputText id="FirstName" @bind-Value="author.FirstName" />
    </p>

    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</EditForm>
@code {
    Author author = new Author();

    private void SaveAuthor()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(author.FirstName);
    }
    public class Author
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Charls";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I had it in my code. Let me put my github link over here for you to see all the code
https://github.com/maxrena/BlazorServerApp.git

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Do you mean that your code is similar to mine, and still it does not work ? Did you post a link to your app so that I can look into the issue more closely. Please explain...

Comment: I mean, I initiated author already, but in different way. I hope you can look into my code to tell me what makes the difference. Because I am learning this, I hope I can understand what is what.

Comment: @maxrena, did you read my answer and understood my explanation ? I looked into your code. No you did not initiate or rather instantiate Author. You've just created a public property of the Author type, which initially returns the null value. I wouldn't recommend to use a property, though this is perfectly fine. Anyhow, doing the following solves the problem: public Author author { get; set; } = new Author(); which is equivalent to what I do in my answer above:  Author author = new Author();

Comment: In my answer the code under the title "This is the culprit:" is not mine. This code snippet is from the EditForm class definition. It checks whether the user had provided a Model object or the EditContext object (you can use EditContext instead of Model, depending on your design and needs). Now if your Model is null, which is because you do not instantiate it, and you've defined no EditContext, you get the exception InvalidOperationException (see the code above)...even the text message should by now be familiar to you.

Comment: Please, don't hesitate to ask me any question if you're not sure what I'm talking about. Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: God, thank you a lot, that's understandable and really helpful for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 9):

To enable the server load data without firing an exception, you can use the next code:

```
@if (author== null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
  <EditForm Model="@author">
  ....
</EditForm>
``
```

Comment: Correct - if part of your form is from an async operation you must check the data for null.

Comment: I'm new to razor and omg thank you. I must do async Task loads of data and this saved my sanity.

Comment: NOTE: If you have 2 or more objects that require instantiating within the `OnInitializedAsync` then you need to use an OR in the `if` statement above.
i.e. `@if (author== null || myOtherObject == null) { <p><em>Loading...</em></p> } else { ... show something ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error. The error message said the same thing about an edit form which wasn't the page needing to be changed. The problem was the actual (Blazor) page causing the error kept trying to use a null object. Because I used the rest api, the page gave me the editform error because the rest api had to await data so it could instantiate the object. (The object is also a model by the way.) I resolved this in the page having the null object problem by using a conditional. If (object == null) return; So, when I did a debug trace, I found the code behind repeatedly going back to the OnInitializedAsync function and then to the page until the rest api returned and instantiated the page object. After the object was  instantiated, the conditional in my page passed because the object was no longer null. The problem than was resolved.