# Simple Parameter Passing in Blazor (Previously TempData)

Tags: c#, blazor, parameter-passing, blazor-component

I am very new to Blazor (coming from a medium level of asp.net experience).

Previously, I used ViewBag & TempData to pass variables from one component to another, quite effectively and easily.  This is not avail in Blazor and I am struggling to understand how to pass a variable to another component.  I have, indeed, read many posts and online resources. But they don't seem to make sense to me, for what I am trying to do.

I tried to make a very simple example of what I am trying to accomplish:

When the NewEntry.razor page loads, I need to create a new GUID for the new record entry that stuff will create (newID).

```
[Parameter]
public Guid NewRecord {get; set;} = Guid.NewGuid();
private Guid newID = Guid.Empty;
AddCarDialog addCarDialog; 


protected override OnInitialized()
{
newID = NewRecord;
base.OnInitialized();
}
```

Now, when I place '@newID' anywhere on the NewEntry.razor page, it shows the new GUID correctly.

I need to pass @newID to the AddCarDialog page in the shared folder. After spending more than a day on this, I am asking for help.

This is where I am at in my Showpopup code on the NewEntry.razor.cs page, that opens AddCarDialog.

```
protected void Showpopup()
{
addCarDialog.carPK = newID;
addCarDialog.ShowDialog = true;
}
```

Code for AddCarDialog.razor.cs

```
[Parameter]
public Guid carPk {get; set} = new
```

Code to display on AddCarDialog.razor

```
@carPk
```

EDIT/Update:

I am now using the example below, from Dimitris, and not receiving any errors.  However, I am noticing another issue

When NewEntry.razor loads, AddCarDialog.razor loads twice!  I set a break OnInitialized, to see what is happening.  Here is what I know:

NewEntry.razor loads. Before fully loading, AddCarDialog loads once, and carPK is correct.  Then, for some odd reason, AddCarDialog loads a second time and carPK is empty.

I need to figure out why it's loading twice here and how to stop it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the error of this Blazor EditForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319067/what-is-the-error-of-this-blazor-editform)

Comment: I'm assuming "EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter" is an error on  `AddCarDialog`.  However, you show no such code block in your question, (so it's impossible to figure out what is going on) just some code setting parameters and an attempt to manually set up a component which @Dimitris Maragkos has addressed in his answer.

Comment: After some research, I don't believe the 'EditForm' is the issue.  I had changed it to an editable form, testing how to do this, and forgot to set it back.  I no longer get the edit error.  But I am still not passing the parameter, properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** instantiate Blazor components manually and pass parameters to them from code. The following is wrong:

```cs
AddCarDialog addCarDialog = new();
addCarDialog.CarPk = newID;
```

instead you should use the component like this:

`NewEntry.razor:`

```
...

<AddCarDialog CarPk="@newID" @bind-Visible="isDialogVisible" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Guid NewRecord { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    private Guid newID = Guid.Empty;

    private bool isDialogVisible = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        newID = NewRecord;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void ShowDialog()
    {
        isDialogVisible = true;
    }
}
```

And `AddCarDialog.razor`:

```
@if (Visible)
{
    @*dialog implementation*@
    <button @onclick="Close">Close dialog</button>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Guid CarPk { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> VisibleChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task Close()
    {
        await VisibleChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. I am trying to implement it within my own code.  I am no longer getting any errors.  However, the Guid parameter is not passing.  In NewEntry.razor I added <AddCarDialog CarPk="@newID" @bind-Visible="isDialogVisible" />, and when the page loads, it shows a new Guid, properly.   On AddCarDialog.razor, I have added <h3>Batch: @carPk</h3>, but that shows an empty GUID.  I am doing something wrong.  I need @carPk to show the same guid as NewEntry.razor.

Comment: Take a look at this [demo](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/g7dgz53a) which might help. If you still have problems please create a demo with the code that reproduces the issue so we can take a look.

Comment: Thank you Dimitris!  That demo was so helpful.  I can't even say enough.  Using that demo, I was able to see my problem instantly.  I had the my <AddCarDialog /> all wrong. Somehow I did not notice that until the side by side comparison.  I am now passing the parameter properly!  THANK YOU !!